# Editing the bodies of emails sent in the "Request a Copy" process

Tags: dspace

I would like to edit the bodies of emails sent in the Dspace "Request a Copy" process.  Documentation says that there are keys that can be edited in the JSPUI 'Messages.properties' file, but we are using Mirage2, and XMLUI.  I found the one in the email templates directory, as well as the messages.xml file. It's the message templates below I want to alter:

```
itemRequest.response.body.approve   
itemRequest.response.body.reject    
itemRequest.response.body.contactAuthor
itemRequest.response.body.contactRequester
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. change `[dspace-src]/dspace-api/src/main/resources/Messages.properties` -- note in this case you will need to use the full build option (invoke maven in [dspace-src]); **or**
2. copy that file to `[dspace-src]/dspace/modules/additions/src/main/resources/Messages.properties` and edit the latter. You'll probably have to create that directory hierarchy first. You will be able to use the full or the quick build option.